# Converting several html files into one word file

Tags: html, ms-word

I received web-service documentation in html format, but it is very unfriendly when it comes to search for a specific word. Using index file it displays list of names of each request on the left and when you click on a particular one then on the right it displays description and content of this request.

Unfortunately I have to do some mapping with web-services that we already have. When searching through `CTRL + F` it only goes trough the left side (list), doesn't matter if you place cursor over the description on the right, click and try to search this way too - it doesn't work.

My idea is to extract all html files that have been provided to us into one word document (this way I can go through descriptions not only trough the list of names). Unfortunately all I can reach is that these files open in separate word files (one html file per one word file). It's almost 1000 requests to be mapped and working this way is going to take forever...

So the question is: **How to combine more than one html file into one word file?**

Comment: was you problem solved?

Comment: what is the OS that you are using?

Comment: type *.html > output.html works! 
I have Windows 10 :)

Comment: If it works can you please give an upvote and confirm the answer

Comment: Unfortunately I am too new user and I cannot leave my vote yet in the way that it shows:"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score". I'll leave my comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There two ways to merge html files

**Using Command Line**

1. Copy all html files that you want to merge into a folder.
2. Navigate to that folder using terminal or command prompt.
3. Execute following commands

on Mac/Linux

```
cat *.html > output.html
```

on Windows :

```
type *.html > output.html
```

**Using already available tools**

- https://www.sobolsoft.com/howtouse/combine-html-files.htm,  [html-merge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/htmlmg/files/) (Windows Only)

In order to convert merged html file to a word document, read [here](http://code.makery.ch/library/convert-web-page-to-word/).

Comment: I have Windows 10 and the command user158 provided works beautifully! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MariaT My pleasure. Can you please accept the answer since it answers your question.